# How to animate object rotation on a single local axis when local and global axis not aligned?

Tags: animation, transforms

In the animation I want rotation locked to a single local axis like when you press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> twice to rotate.

An example would be a wheel rotating on an axle.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12211/why-are-keyframes-in-global-coords-instead-of-local-coords-blender-2-70a/12254#12254

Comment: Then what is the question? You already wrote how to do it.

Comment: @someonewithpc They said they want it locked, presumably so it can only rotate on that local axis and no other.

Comment: It says "when you press r then x twice". That locks rotation to the local X axis.

Comment: @someonewithpc that locks the rotation for that rotation operation only. In the object panel there are permanent transformation locks, but I am not sure if they are local or global.

Comment: it does interpolate and the axis lock is lost

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply use the **Copy Rotation** contraint:

- Create a new empty;
- Select your object, switch to **Constraints** tab in **Properties** Editor, add a **Copy Rotation** constraint, set the empty as *Target*, toggle *Offset*, set *Local Space* as the owner space (current object).
- Then you control the rotation by rotating the empty.

[image]

### [image]

**Tip:** For quick constraint creation, you can also first select the empty, then holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select your target object, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> -> Copy Rotation.

Comment: turns out it doesn't work when my cone mesh is a child of another object.... anyway to keep this working when the cone is a child of another mesh/parent?

Answer (score 3):

I would add an armature to the object. The armature only needs to have a single bone that is aligned to the objects axis and you can parent your object to the bone without bothering with weight painting. The bone can then easily be animated on it's axis and if you use Euler rotation you can have one f-curve to adjust the animation.

[image]

Transform locks can also limit the possible rotations if you only want to rotate on one axis.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a very simple solution by playing around.

Go to the timeline. Insert a Delta Rotation Keyframe at the start.

[image: insert keyframe]

Then go to the object panel and chance the Delta Rotation values of the particular axis you wish to rotate. And then just add a new Delta Rotation keyframe. There you have a very simple animation of a rotation on a single axis.

[image: rotation keyframed]