# Object wobbles during rotation

Tags: animation

newbie here - I'm trying to rotate an object - I can rotate it no problem in object mode, but when I set the keyframes and play the animation it wobbles. I tried uploading the file but it's over 200MB :(
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene. Consider uploading your file so that others can inspect it. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the  resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: I think [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15746/935) has some answers that should help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are rotating using the local axis in the top one, and the global axis in the bottom one.

To solve your problem, use the local axis when keyframing

So in order to rotate around say, the x aixs, instead of <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>move mouse</kbd>, use <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>move mouse</kbd>

Comment: Please explain how to use local axis when keyframing, without that yor answer is inclomplete.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I tried the RXX but still wobbles  %$#@!.  I am rotating it on a custom axis in the top one but when animated it uses something completely different.

Comment: @Darbla Provide a sample blend file so we can inspect the issue