# Blender rotates objects on wrong axis during animation playback

Tags: animation, transforms, axis

Recently I asked a question "I have an object that is slanted on all 3 axes, and I need to rotate its bottom on its own axis."
And the answer was simple - Local transform orientation.

But it doesn`t work during animation playback. I set keyframes, rotate the object manually - everything looks good untill I press play - and it rotates under unknown axis\angle. Anything else to tweak or is it kind of a bug?

Comment: The "problem" you are facing is concerning rotation order. In the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/transforms.html#options-in-object-mode), it is refered to as *rotation mode* and not documented well. In the properties panel, under rotation, select a rotation mode where the *desired axis* (which you rotate around) stands at the first position. E. g. If i want to rotate the cube around it's local Z axis, I would choose ZYX or ZXY, **then** rotate it and set the keyframes.

Comment: There are a number of solutions discussed in this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15746/how-to-animate-object-rotation-on-a-single-local-axis-when-local-and-global-axis

Comment: Yay! Selecting Rotation in properties panel totally works! Many thanks!

Comment: Strange, though, once worked but not anymore. What a sorcery...