# Animation: create a rotation around the object z-axis instead of global z-axis

Tags: animation, transforms

I'm creating an animation where I rotate an object, insert a LocRotScale keyframe (via the <kbd>I</kbd> key), select another frame, rotate the object again and insert a LocRotScale keyframe.

For example I use this:

<kbd>Z</kbd>, 190, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now I want to rotate the object around its own z-axis instead of the global z-axis.
I've found out if you press the [Z] two times you get the Local axis instead of Global.

For example I do this now:

<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, 190, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The rotation is ok, but when I insert the LocRotScale keyframe it did the rotation, but not around the Normal axis, but it used the Global axis.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set  Rotation type to ZXY Euler, then the animation around the local axes works like a charm.

[image]

Here is an Example Blend File for inspection: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31685

Comment: I've tried that already.
Looks like the same problem: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12211/why-are-keyframes-in-global-coords-instead-of-local-coords-blender-2-70a (see the YouTube video in the post)

In the comments they suggest to create an empty. Where can this be found?

Comment: I added my example Blend file to my answer. Unless i misunderstood your issue completely it works as i described it.

Comment: It works indeed, but I had Local enabled instead of Global, which gave me another output. wish this was easier in Blender.

Comment: Funny that this is the simplest way in all of the google results and YouTube vids. Did you even have YouTube back in 2014? :P Most want to use a constraint or parent to empty. I couldn't figure those out. 2022 Rep'yo'city