# transfer same rotation in graph editor and 3d view

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes, graph-editor

When I change the rotation of a certain bone (e.g. the bone of an upper-arm) in 3d view on only one axis (e.g. ' X '), all three curves in the graph editor are automatically changed when I set a keyframe and not only one curve.

Therefore, changing the rotation in the graph editor by changing the keyframes would be easier than to work in 3d view where all 3 axes are automatically changed. But since I work with Quaternion I would like to avoid using the graph editor to adjust the rotation of a bone because the W rotation wouldn't be automatically adjusted.

Is there a way to have the same effect when changing the rotation of one axis in 3d view as it is in the graph editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to inserting a keyframe for a single channel. Of course with quaternions the minimum number of axis are two (because how quaternions works)
[image]

Comment: But that only seems to show the rotation on only the selected axes e.g. if I added the X rotation to the Keying Set and only change the Y axis, the X-curve will be affected. What I would like to know is how to affect only e.g. the X axis when rotating the bone by pressing R + X and not the other axes.

Comment: So the bone only moves to one direction. It's like you change the axes from global to local to have the chance to affect only one axis for the location.

Comment: automatic Keying will write to all you channel, but if you press I for the following poses the box axis it'll keep inserting only in that channel. Or maybe I have not understood what you are asking for. It's rather confused to me...

Comment: As I wrote with quaternions the minimum number of axis are two (because how quaternions works) W + X or Y or Z

Comment: First of all sorry for the bad explanation. Let me retry my question. If there is the possibility for rotations to change the axes from global to local, it'd be helpful e.g. if you want to rotate an arm while the body has already been rotated. If you rotate it on the global X-axis to swing the arm back, the arm would not be rotated along the body but in an unwanted direction (e.g. through the body). But if you change the axes to local the arm will swing in the wanted direction. I only know that changing the axes from global to local works with locations, but does it also work with rotations?

Comment: sure select Local orientation then press R and double press X for a local rotation on X (same for Y and Z)

Comment: maybe related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12211/why-are-keyframes-in-global-coords-instead-of-local-coords-blender-2-70a